# text file sorting

Tags: text-processing, command-line, sort

I have a log file like

```
name = CE_20_122 assigned_hostnames = host1 cpuset_name = usr_1397032 
name = CE_21_122 assigned_hostnames = host4 cpuset_name = usr_1397028 
name = CE_22_122 assigned_hostnames = host4 cpuset_name = usr_1397024 
 .
 .
 .
name = CE_76_122 assigned_hostnames = host27 cpuset_name = usr_1397012 
name = CE_77_122 assigned_hostnames = host28 cpuset_name = usr_1397128
```

The command

```
sort logfile
```

sorts the lines as a whole.

How do I sort lines by one of the columns, e.g. by `hostX` or by `usr_X`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by hostX:

> sort -nk 6.6

by usr_X

> sort -nk 9.6

Answer (score 1):

In Vim:

```
:sort n /host\d*/
```

to sort by host, and

```
:sort n /usr_\d*/
```

to sort by user. Since using vim for the first time can be overwhelming, you could do this from the command line instead.

```
vim file.txt -c "sort n /host\d*/" -c "wq"
```

or

```
vim file.txt -c "sort n /usr_\d*/" -c "wq"
```